# How do I send multiple data under the same array variable to a sub-partial?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to display two columns of articles: published and unpublished. The articles are separately sent in two arrays via the controller as (**$pubArticles** and **$unpubArticles**) to the view. However, the view partial uses the same sub-partial to build both the columns-- where **$articles** is supposed to get different values from the array. How do I achieve this?

**Controller**

```
public function index(Article $article)
{
    // published articles
    $pubArticles = $article->latest('published_at')->published()->get();
    // unpublished articles
    $unpubArticles = $article->oldest('published_at')->unpublished()->get();
    return view('articles.index', compact('pubArticles','unpubArticles'));
}
```

**View: articles/index.blade.php**

```
@section('content')

    <div class="col-md-6">
        // i want to display published articles here
        @include('articles._listall', [$pubArticles,  'publishText' => 'Published', ])
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        // i want to display unpublished articles here
        @include('articles._listall', [$unpubArticles, 'publishText' => 'Will be Published'])
    </div>
@endsection
```

**Sub-Partial: listall.blade.php**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body no-padding">
            @foreach ($articles as $article)
                <div class="well">
                    <article>
                        <a href="{{ url('/articles/' . $article->id) }} ">
                            <h4>{{ $article->title }}</h4>
                        </a>
                        <p>{{ $article->body }}</p>
                    </article>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

change your **View: articles/index.blade.php**

```
@section('content')

    <div class="col-md-6">
        // i want to display published articles here
        @include('articles._listall', ['panelTitle' => 'ON THE SITE', 'publishText' => 'Published',$Articles => $pubArticles ])
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        // i want to display unpublished articles here
        @include('articles._listall', ['panelTitle' => 'IN THE FUTURE', 'publishText' => 'Will be Published',$Articles => $unpubArticles])
    </div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return view('articles.index', array('pubArticles'=>$pubArticles, 'unpubArticles'=>$unpubArticles));
```

Comment: Sorry, but the problem isn't about how to send data to the view from controller but how to send data from a view partial to a view sub-partial.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The problem was that the name of the variable, not the variable itself should be set as the key.

```
@section('content')
    <div class="col-md-6">
        // i want to display published articles here
        @include('articles._listall', ['articles' => $pubArticles, 'publishText' => 'Published'])
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        // i want to display unpublished articles here
        @include('articles._listall', [ 'articles' => $unpubArticles, 'publishText' => 'Will be Published'])
    </div>
@endsection
```